# Change maximum number of items in paging navigation

Tags: catalog

On catalog page there is a pagination links that look like this (for 17 pages):

```
<- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 17 ->
```

Is there any way to reduce number of items before `...` without rewriting paging block completely? So it'll look like this:

```
<- 1 2 3 4 ... 17 ->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the config section:
`System -> Configuration -> Design -> Pagination`